# Rails build assocation before_create doesn't save records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, patch

I have a student which has multiple products. Products can be selected to generate an invoice. This is the generate function:

```
def generate
  @student = @driving_school.students.find(params[:student_id])
  @products = @student.products.find(params[:product_ids])

  @invoice = @driving_school.invoices.build({student_id: @student.id})
  @invoice.reference = @student.full_name
  @invoice.products = @products
  @invoice.payment_is_due_in = 14

  if @invoice.save!
    redirect_to @invoice
  else
    redirect_to @invoice
  end
end
```

The invoice contains lines, which are generated when creating the invoice using a before_create filter.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
...
before_create :copy_products_to_lines 
...
private

def copy_products_to_lines
  self.products.each do |product|
    self.lines.build(
      invoice_id: self.id,
      description: product.name + ' ' + product.description,
      amount: product.amount,
      price: product.netto,
      vat: true,
      vat_rate: product.vat_rate,
      undeletable: true
    )
  end
end
```

In rails 3.1.3 this has always worked perfectly well. Since updating to 3.1.10 because of the latest vulnerability in Rails this code broke. The invoice is generated successfully, but the lines are not created anymore. Does anyone know how come?

Comment: I'm surprised this worked in 3.1.3. Surely self.id is nil, since the invoice has not been saved yet. What happens if you change the callback to `after_create`?

Comment: Wrong copy-paste, the line said self.lines.build. So the lines should be saved when invoice is saved right? After_create doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Going to be extremely hard to debug without seeing the logs really.

Comment: Are the products saved as well ? Did you try adding `has_many :lines, :autosave => true`

Comment: Charlysisto's answer was actually correct. Had to add autosave: true. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding has_many :lines, autosave: true solved it. Thanks charlysisto.